# Why can't I get response from this web service?

Tags: jquery, https

Why can't I get the response from this web service?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://aip-rest.appspot.com/api/token/12416689"
    }).then(function(data) {
       $('.greeting-id').append(data.id);
       $('.greeting-content').append(data.content);
    });
});
```

I have tested the same code with http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting and it's working.

Comment: It seems that in the response of https://aip-rest.appspot.com/api/token/12416689 there's no "id" or "content", right?

Answer (score 0):

The web service https://aip-rest.appspot.com/api/token/12416689 is giving you a XML response, so you have to indicate that to the ajax call...

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://aip-rest.appspot.com/api/token/12416689",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xmlData) {
        // Fetch your $(xmlData) to extract what you need
    }
});
```

I hope it helps